# listing a subcollection array's objects by sorting property of mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

**I want to sort the items in array of my collection's sub-collection.I can list them but not in the way that i want.I want them to sort by 'no' properties of item array objects**

> My Collection Schema

```
const itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({

  item: [{ name: String, no: Number }],

});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Item", itemSchema);
```

**My End-Point**

```
getItems(req, res) {
    try {
      Item.find({ _id: req.item._id }, (err, founds) => {
        if (err) {
          res
            .status(httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .json({ message: "error occured!", err });
        }

        res.send(founds[0].item);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      res
        .status(httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        .json({ message: "display item error", error });
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using aggregation.
First we are [matching](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) the documents, then [unwinding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), [sorting](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and lastly [grouping](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

```js
  Item.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5df7c5121debf22a388da1c7")
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$item"
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        "item.no": -1  //1 (for ascending) or -1 (for descending)
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        item: {
          $push: "$item"
        }
      }
    }
  ])
    .then(founds => {
      if (founds.length > 0) {
        res.send(founds[0]);
      } else {
        res.status(400).send("No doc found");
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res
        .status(httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        .json({ message: "error occured!", err });
    });
```

Comment: thank you very much..I only added some part and worked like res.send(founds[0].item);

Comment: @MehmetAkifArslan you are welcolme, after finding the document. you can decide what to return the whole document or a sub field.